# why use the operator `$` is very time consuming than use `.jcall` expression

Tags: r, rjava

I knew two type of expression to call java interface in R.for example there is a java function definition  `public void add(int a,int b){}` in class `Test`

---

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath(dir( "lib", full.names=T ))

Test = J('...Test')
test = new(Test)
a = as.integer(3)
b = as.integer(4)
.jcall(test,'V','add',a,b) #first type of expression
test$add(a,b) #second type of expression
```

---

I tested  tow kind of expressions, the first type is much more efficient than the second.I want to know the details of reason.
thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`rjava`](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) site:

> This interface uses Java reflection API to find the correct method so
>   it is much slower and may not be right (works for simple examples but
>   may not for more complex ones).

So it is slower because of Reflection.